# Length in Compile encounter "type Integer encountered in assignment of Type Real "

Tags: compile

```
Compile[{}, Module[{n}, n = Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]; n = n/2]]
```

The above code will emit errors

> Compile::cset: Variable n of type _Integer encountered in assignment
>   of type _Real. >>
>
> Compile::extscalar: n=n/2 cannot be compiled and will be evaluated
>   externally. The result is assumed to be of type Real. >>
>
> Compile::cset: Variable n of type _Integer encountered in assignment
>   of type _Real. >>
>
> Compile::extscalar: n=n/2 cannot be compiled and will be evaluated
>   externally. The result is assumed to be of type Real. >>

Why? `n = Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]` already make sure that n is integer, Why n=n/2 cannot be compiled?

Comment: When it divides by 2, there's no guarantee that the result will be an integer (even though it is in this case).  You can use n = Round[n/2] to keep the type as an integer

Comment: @JasonB Thanks, `Round` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want integer division, use `Quotient`:

```
Compile[{}, Module[{n}, n = Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]; n = Quotient[n, 2]]]
```

If you want `n` to be real instead of an integer, you can coerce it's type in a number of ways. For example, these will both result in `n` being real:

```
Compile[{}, Module[{n = 0.0}, n = Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]; n = n/2]]

Compile[{}, Module[{n}, n = N[Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]; n = n/2]]
```

If you want to see how `Compile` has interpreted types, you can view the compiled routine like so:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`;

cf = Compile[{}, Module[{n = 0.0}, n = Length[{1, 2, 3, 4}]; n = n/2]];

CompiledFunctionToString[cf]

(*
"
        No argument
        2 Integer registers
        4 Real registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(I1)0 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
        I1 = 2
        R0 = 0.
        Result = R1

1   R1 = R0
2   I0 = Length[ T(I1)0]
3   R2 = I0
4   R1 = R2
5   R2 = I1
6   R3 = Reciprocal[ R2]
7   R2 = R1 * R3
8   R1 = R2
9   Return
"
*)
```

In this output, the integers start with "I" and the reals start with "R".